# how to load data from firebase into arraylist in java

Tags: java, arrays, swift, firebase, dictionary

I have this piece of code in swift which loads up data from Firebase into dictionary a dictionary object.

i need to do same in java but its not dont know how. pl

// This is swift version

```
var yourArray = NSMutableArray()

func GetData() {
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child(bookTitle).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let children = snapshot.children
        let allObj = children.allObjects

        for i in 0 ..< allObj.count {
            self.yourArray.add(allObj[i])
        }

    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. First tip - don't use `NSMutableArray` in Swift. Create a `var` Array of the type of `allObj`'s elements, then just `yourArray.append(contentsOf: allObj)`

Comment: i've try this but crashed my app  myList  = GetData(dataSnapshot); public static ArrayList<QuestionBank> GetData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        ArrayList<QuestionBank> items  = new ArrayList<QuestionBank>();

        for (DataSnapshot item : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                items.add(new QuestionBank(
                        item.child("questionText").getValue().toString(),
                        item.child("optionA").getValue().toString(),
                        item.child("optionB").getValue().toString()
                ));
        }
        return items;
    }

Answer (score -1):

Try This One

```
            List<MyPojoClass> myList = new ArrayList<>();
            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    myList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        MyPojoClass pojo= postSnapshot.getValue(MyPojoClass.class);
                        myList.add(pojo);

                        // here you can access others property of pojo class.

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Comment: to add to my original post my datasnapshot prints like this: